# Why is including multiple files so much slower than bundling into one

Tags: php, performance, include

I have been doing some tests with PHP, and I have noticed that performing `include` on multiple files compare to one containing all the functions is much slower.

My test involved creating 1025 files, 1024 of which contained the text `<?php class cls$i {} ?>` (where $i was the file number), and 1 file that was a concatenation of all the text in the files before. I then had two functions, one for testing each case. The test that loaded the single file took about `6ms` to compile to bytecode and make the contents available to the system, however, the combination of 1024 files took almost `600ms`.

In terms of size, the 1024 individual files are exactly the same size as the single file. I am also running `APC` to cache the bytecode, but in practice, it only shaves off a few milliseconds.

I also created a ramdisk which held all the files, but that was only marginally (10ms on average) faster.

So, having said that, why are individual files SOOOOO much slower than a single file? Is it down to significant inefficiencies in the loading engine within PHP, or have I made a considerable cockup in the configuration (on my local system, a standard AMPPS installation)?

Comment: @mario My Ampps system is running on Windows 8 with NTFS and a RAMDISK emulator, but I have done the same tests on Arch Linux with EXT3 and /tmp, and both were similar down to a few ms, so I thought it irrelevant. I have just finished re-running the code where each class had several static, and several instancable functions, and there was very little change in the results

Answer (score 3):

My first guess is that it's all the `stat` system calls going on.

What happens if you turn `apc.stat` off in your config?

Even though APC caches the bytecode, if `apc.stat=1`, it needs to check the mtime on each file via the filesystem to make sure it doesn't need to be re-read.

*EDIT*: going deeper, in response to your comment.  How are you referencing the included files?  If you're using relative paths, then you're getting the include_path involved.

In other words:

```
include "somefile.php";
```

is likely to be slower than

```
include __DIR__ . '/otherfile.php';
```

Comment: wow, that doubled the load time, down to `300ms` for the larger file set, but it is still a HUGE difference when comparing the same file contents. It can't all be in the seek time

Comment: the test is using `include $b . $i . '.php'` for the larger set where `$b = __DIR__ . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR`, but there was no noticeable difference between that and having `__DIR__ . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $i . '.php'`

Comment: Yeah, those should be equivalent, as they're both absolute.  I wonder if those almost-300ms are just the cost of hitting the cache.  I would expect it to be higher.  What kind of of stats is APC showing you?

Comment: Ah, I see what you mean now, when I drop the absolute part from the file name, I LOSE an additional 70ms... What stats are you looking for? But I don't think its so much of an issue with APC, because not using APC and after a fresh boot, it takes about 10ms for the single file, and 1200ms for the group of files. Yes the difference is much larger, but in terms of relative growth, its the same. So, this seems to be something more to do with PHP, not APC

Comment: When apc gets installed, it drops an apc.php file somewhere that gives you various statistics/graphs about how the cache is behaving.  I just wanted to rule out that it wasn't full, or whatever.  I'm a little surprised that 1024 cache calls are taking quite that long, but I suppose it's possible.  At this point, I think we're getting to the place where we'd need to start profiling the php interpreter itself to figure out where it's spending time.  If I have some time later this week, maybe I'll run some experiments myself.

Comment: well, according to `apc.php`, there are 2050 cached files stored. At first, I thought that having the files referenced via symlinks to their actual directory would have been causing it, but I cut out all the symlinks and it was running at the same speed. But if you could, that would be excellent. I would do it myself, but don't quite know how... But I think it is somewhere between being asked to `include` the file, and the file being interpreted to bytecode, most likely before when the hook (or whatever is used) that APC uses is called

Comment: On second check, APC is only shaving of about 60ms from the load time. It takes 650ms to load with an empty APC, and 590ms (on average) to load after APC has cached the opcodes